# sqlite python insert

Tags: python, sqlite

I have asked similar question before , here is detailed explanation of what i'm trying to achieve

I have two sqlite tables
table1  - is standard table - has fields like server,id,status
table2 - has fields like server,id,status,number,logfile

Table2 is empty and Table1 has values. I'm trying to fill table2 with entries from table1.
I can retrieve records from table1 ,but while trying to insert into table2 it fails.(but inserting a single field works)

```
self.cursor.execute("select * from server_table1 limit (?)",t)
#insert into server_process

for record in self.server_pool_list:
    print "--->",record # geting output like ---> (u'cloud_sys1', u'free', u'192.168.1.111')
    self.cursor.execute("insert into server_table2(server,status,id) values (?,?,?)",(record[0],)(record[1],),(record[2],));
```

And also let me know how to produce more useful error messages when insert fails

Comment: Copy and paste the error that is generated.

Comment: Yes..thanks I solved it .
I should have used this

(?,?,?"),(record[0],record[1],record[2],)

instead of above ... Now it's working :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This statement is broken:

```
self.cursor.execute("insert into server_table2(server,status,id) values (?,?,?)",(record[0],)(record[1],),(record[2],));
```

it should read:

```
self.cursor.execute("insert into server_table2(server,status,id) values (?,?,?)",record[0:2])
```

And you might want to look into `executemany` as I think it could save you a ton of time.