# sqlite python insert with where condition

Tags: python, sqlite, insert

from this post [sqlite python insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130641/sqlite-python-insert) I learned inserting into tables but now I need to use where something like

cursor.execute("insert into table1(id) values (?) where ip=? and address=?",(id,),(ip,),(addr,));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

INSERT does not have a WHERE clause. I think you mean UPDATE.

Comment: oops extremely sorry for this funny question :) lol  ..yes ...it's update I'll try update statement

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention: good job on using the auto-escaping OO query framework. Most people don't figure that out, and end up accidentally allowing SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT`. If you want to specify the values for particular fields to insert, put them in the values clause:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table1(id, ip, address) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (id, ip, addr))
```